# Why can't I adjust the height of flex items using "align-items: stretch" when the flex container is a scroll box?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I have two elements inside a scroll box like this. However, here the left element does not match the right element. The element on the left ignores `align-items` and matches the height of the scroll box.

Why is this, can I match the height of the left element with the right element?

I guess there is a duplicate question on this issue, but for now I haven't found it.

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch; /* not worked. why? */
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  background: green;
}

.item1 {
  background: red; /* doesnt stretch */
}

.item2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item1">
    <span>sample text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

align-item:center; in box class

and give height as needed in item1 and item2

item2 is not taking full height as item1 because of margin:auto in item1

Comment: It uses center instead of stretch, so you can't stretch the height between two elements, right?

Comment: what align-item:stretch does is makes the flex-child  heights equal. but when you used margin auto in item2, it only takes the height and width as need or value in height and width, and centers it self vertically and horizontally

Comment: `but when you used margin auto ` ...  I removed `margin` but still stretch didn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/8kuf5o74/

Comment: remove height:500px  also

Comment: Certainly it matches the height, but I can't change this height. Also, in normal flexbox, the stretch works even if the height is specified for the flex item. Why should I remove the height in this case?

Comment: 1. you have width: 100vw;height: 100vh;align-item:stretch; in box. what alignitem stretch is doing in this case is to make the height of its child same. 2. you gave item2 height 500px ;  which in this case is larger than 100vh. 3. box tried to make the child height same but it was unable to make the height of item1 equal to item2 because item2's height is greater then its own height.

Comment: If this helped feel free to mark this answer as accepted. You should read flex documentation.

Comment: I found it difficult to use align-items: stretch in a scroll box. Yes, it was very helpful. Thank you very much.